# Android Development Button

Tags: android, button

I am learning to make android apps and I have a problem with my hello world programs buttons.
Here's my code:

```
 package com.Norwood.helloandroid; import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android.");
       setContentView(tv);
   }
   public void onclick01(View View)  
   {  
       Toast.makeText(this, "Will change in 1.2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   }  

   public void onclick02(View View)  
   {  
       Toast.makeText(this, "Will change in 1.2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   }  
}
```

And my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="60sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:minHeight="92sp"
        android:onClick="onclick01"
        android:text="@string/ChangeCoulour"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minHeight="92sp"
        android:onClick="onclick02"
        android:text="@string/Change_Text_Colour"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I run the app both on the emulator and on my android the buttons don't show up.
And they show up in the graphical layout of the XML file.

Thanks
Collin N.

Comment: Next time, if you have an Error, please post the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourXml)
```

You cannot do it your way because you must set your view to your xml first. have setContentview on the line after onCreate

```
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android.");
       setContentView(tv);//wrong
```

**reply to comment:**
Like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_XML_FILE_NAME);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android.");

   }
```